# How can I take a photo every 1 min with my Fujifilm HS10?

Tags: timelapse, tethering, remote, intervalometer, fujifilm

I have a Fujifilm HS10 and I'd like to put the camera somewhere and take a photo from a scene every say 1 min. How can I do it? Is there any option in the camera to do it? If I connect to the camera via USB, can I shoot the picture by sending a command from my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

The Fujifilm HS10 doesn't have any built-in mechanism for doing this.

There is a [chap on the myFinePix forums](http://www.myfinepix.co.uk/forum/3/246090) who has built a bracket to allow a remote shutter trigger. This could (in theory) be hooked up to a mechanical intervalometer.

I could not find information about a way of remotely controlling the camera from a computer using the USB socket.

Answer (score 0):

Most cameras are accessible via ptp. I do not know of universally usable gui tools that work with every camera, but if you don't fear console applications you can use gphoto (at least under linux). 
With gphoto you can access almost every setting on most cameras via usb.

Comment: It does look like Fuji cameras in general (and this model specifically) don't allow remote capture, according to the gphoto documentation (http://www.gphoto.org/doc/remote/) and Fuji's site (http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/compatibility/utility/)

Comment: Thanks guys. This looks really weird to me. These cameras look like old cellphones with no connectivity method to me. Of course, this is a firmware issue, not a hardware one. Therefore, a firmware update might fix the problem. However, it seems Fuji is unlikely to do that. Just another question, are you aware of any custom (third party) firmware for the camera?

Comment: Like this one? http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK_in_Brief